# Creating our own Git server

Tags: git, version-control, jgit, scmmanager

I'm trying to build versioning system using jgit api for all git operation. Need suggestions to create git server/ any software that is compatible with jgit api  for creating remote repository , We cant use github the reason i am building platform for people they wont have any idea about git and  github instead they uses our created software to create / delete / update / rollback / save files .

I'm able to create git server like below but looking if we have any tools or software that i can use which is compatible with jgit api to create remote repository and all .

```html
public class GitServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Repository repository = createNewRepository();

        populateRepository(repository);

        // Create the JGit Servlet which handles the Git protocol
        GitServlet gs = new GitServlet();
        gs.setRepositoryResolver((req, name) -> {
            repository.incrementOpen();
            return repository;
        });

        // start up the Servlet and start serving requests
        Server server = configureAndStartHttpServer(gs);

        // finally wait for the Server being stopped
        server.join();
    }

    private static Server configureAndStartHttpServer(GitServlet gs) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
        server.setHandler(handler);

        ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(gs);

        handler.addServletWithMapping(holder, "/*");

        server.start();
        return server;
    }

    private static void populateRepository(Repository repository) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
        // enable pushing to the sample repository via http
        repository.getConfig().setString("http", null, "receivepack", "true");

        try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
            File myfile = new File(repository.getDirectory().getParent(), "testfile");
            if(!myfile.createNewFile()) {
                throw new IOException("Could not create file " + myfile);
            }

            git.add().addFilepattern("testfile").call();

            System.out.println("Added file " + myfile + " to repository at " + repository.getDirectory());

            git.commit().setMessage("Test-Checkin").call();
        }
    }

    private static Repository createNewRepository() throws IOException {
        // prepare a new folder
        File localPath = File.createTempFile("TestGitRepository", "");
        if(!localPath.delete()) {
            throw new IOException("Could not delete temporary file " + localPath);
        }

        if(!localPath.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("Could not create directory " + localPath);
        }

        // create the directory
        Repository repository = FileRepositoryBuilder.create(new File(localPath, ".git"));
        repository.create();

        return repository;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check bellow code for local git

https://github.com/masumcse1/mygitserver

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please do this one